# Poco: How to abort a blocking socket operation from another thread

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

Is there a proper way in Poco to abort a blocking I/O operation from another thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the thread doing the I/O would be blocked, I don't see any direct way of going in there an cancelling it, besides being nasty and killing the thread explicitly.  This is however **not advised**

Comment: @AlexanderVassilev: Try Go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call Socket::shutdown(). What happens after that depends on your platform, when recv() returns Poco will throw appropriate exception.

But you do not have to do blocking I/O to start with, since there is [Poco::Net::Socket::setBlocking(bool)](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/include/Poco/Net/Socket.h#L261) to enable or disable blocking behavior. Or, even if you want to do blocking, you can still define timeout using [Poco::Net::Socket::setSendTimeout()](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/include/Poco/Net/Socket.h#L157) or [Poco::NetSocket::setReceiveTimeout()](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/include/Poco/Net/Socket.h#L167)